# fstream is not writing anything on the file

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to write some things to a text file but it won't even create the file. I will appreciate a lot if you can help me with this. Thanks.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("path/to/file");

    //write something to file
    file << "test";

    //printing to screen
    std::cout << file.rdbuf();  

    //closing file
    file.close(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You check the result of `salesFile.open("C:\\Users\\Tebsan\\Desktop\\Coding\\c++\\re\\salesFile.txt");` first, eg. using `if(salesFile)`

Comment: I tried this:

    if (salesFile.is_open()){
  salesFile << "Month: " << month << " " << year << "\n";
  salesFile << "--------------------" << "\n";
  .
                .
                .
 }
 else
 {
  std::cout << "Error opening file";
 }

But it doesn't show any error, and the problem persists...

Answer (score 4):

The following line is your culprit:

```
std::cout << file.rdbuf();
```

You cannot use `rdbuf` to output a file that was opened for write operations only.

Remove that line and your file will be written correctly.

---

If you want to read your file after you've finished writing to it:

**Solution 1:**
Open `file` for both read and write operations using `fstream`:

```
std::fstream file("path/to/file", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
// ... write to file

file.seekg(0); // set read position to beginning of file
std::cout << file.rdbuf();
```

**Solution 2:**
Create a new `std::ifstream` to read from file:

```
 // ... write to file
 file.close(); // call `close` to make sure all input is written to file

 std::ifstream inputFile("path/to/file");
 std::cout << inputFile.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
salesFile.open("C:\\Users\\Tebsan\\Desktop\\Coding\\c++\\re\\salesFile.txt"); // ...try to open existing file
    if( !salesFile.is_open() ) // ...else, create new file...
        salesFile.open("C:\\Users\\Tebsan\\Desktop\\Coding\\c++\\re\\salesFile.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);
```

You have to call fstream::open with an explicit openmode argument of

```
ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc
```

Otherwise open will fail due to ENOENT.

Comment: I just tried that, but the file is still not being created. The weird thing is that when I execute the program, the console prints the content with <iomanip> attributes, and I commented out  all that section so that I could know if the file was created or not...

Comment: @war1oc It's an `ofstream` (c.f. `fstream`) so it will automatically open in the `ios::out` mode.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i just ran your code and weirdly it works and the file is being created. have you checked the path correctly? if u use "std::cout << file.rdbuf();" a lot of garbage ("Í") is being printed to the file along with what was written through the code. sorry if i couldn't be of much help

Comment: Hmm, it didn't print any garbage for me, maybe a `flush` or `close` somewhere would prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!!!
I Learned new things from this. The funny thing is that the issue was the name of the file, apparently the name was too long, and for the new file that included file stream I just added stream at the end of the name, so the compiler kept running the first file (without file stream)...